# with “s” or without “s”

Tags: adjectives, plural-forms

Is that sentence right and sound correct at all (about "both")?

I think "time" is an adjective. This is true?

> 'At, in, on' and ''to' are used as both time(***s***) prepositions and place prepositions in English.

Comment: Why do you think that *time* would be treated any differently than *place*? (Perhaps you are confusing ***as*** *both time* with ***at*** *both times*?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'At, in, on' and ''to' are used as both time prepositions and place prepositions in English.

(s) should not be added.

> I think "time" is an adjective. This is true?

True. It may also be referred to as an adjectival noun, noun modifier, or attributive noun.

When applying a noun as an adjective, it's usually singular. There are various exceptions including "sports car", "arms race", and others.